# Unable to implement logout functionality using node and passport js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am new to node js and currently making a boilerplate using passport js, react, and redux. I am facing issues while implementing log out functionality as I am unable to log out. Can anybody help me out in this scenario?

```
function RightMenu(props) {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  const logoutHandler = () => {
    let token = user.loginSuccess.token;
    //console.log(user.loginSuccess.token);
    axios
      .get(`/api/auth/logout`, { headers: { Authorization: `${token}` } })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(user, response);
        if (response.status === 200) {
          props.history.push("/login");
        } else {
          alert("Log Out Failed");
        }
      });
  };
  if (user.loginSuccess) {
    return (
      <Menu mode={props.mode}>
        <Menu.Item key="logout">
          <a onClick={logoutHandler}>Logout</a>
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Menu mode={props.mode}>
      <Menu.Item key="mail">
        <a href="/login">Signin</a>
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="app">
        <a href="/register">Signup</a>
      </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  );
}

export default withRouter(RightMenu);
```

logout route-

```
router.get(
  "api/auth/logout",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.user._id },
      { token: "", isAuth: false },
      (err, doc) => {
        if (err) return res.json({ success: false, err });
       req
          .logout()
          .then(res.json({ message: "Suceesfully loggedout" }))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      }
    );
  }
);
```

I am getting an error message "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" for the **logout method**

Comment: Your route is `/logout`, but you are calling `/api/auth/logout` on the client. Is that the problem?

Comment: If that's not it, then please elaborate by what you mean by "I am unable to log out". Do you get an error? Do you get anything on the server console when you do it? Have you tried adding a console.log output in the `logout` route to see whether it is called? You should always try a few things first before you ask a question on SO and indicate what you've already tried, as those things can help others a lot help you.

Comment: Hello Christian, I have made the necessary changes to the question as mentioned by you, can you please go through it??!!!

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. What is `req`, meaning, which router do you use? What is the logout method? is that injected by a library passport? Can you point to the reference for that? Seems like it just doesn't return anything (or at least not a promise).

Comment: I have used passport.js, passport-jwt, jsonwebtoken packages for authentication; req and res are the corresponding request and response that will be produced after the token gets authenticated successfully. Yes logout method is injected by passport

Answer (score 1):

The [passport documentation of logout](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/logout/) really doesn't state anything about `logout` returning a promise, so unless you know otherwise -- and the error really doesn't suggest so -- I would not assume that it does. So just use:

```
    req.logout();
    res.json({ message: "Successfully logged out" });
```

If there are potential exceptions and wrap it in a try-catch.